# Biostar H61ML - Disable onboard video

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

Well, i'm trying to use my graphic card which is a `GeForce GT520` and I can't disable my onboard graphics (on bios) because i can't find the option. Is there a way to do so with my current bios version: `American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.4, 07/04/2011`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to disable it? Usually when there's not such option in BIOS/UEFI the onboard graphics are automatically disabled when the discrete is detected.

Comment: In that case, how do i know if I have the right settings on my board? I've been following other solved questions (outside superuser) without any success.

Comment: What other settings were you expecting to find at BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: A "primary video adapter" option in which i can choose between Onboard or PCI

Comment: Again, if there's no such setting, the way it works is like I said in the first comment. If everything is fine you should get video when connected to the discrete card. If you don't and get video from the onboard port instead *then* you have a problem.

Comment: I've downloaded the UEFI manual for your board and the setting is actually there (mentioned in page 18): Chipset > North Bridge > Initate (SIC) Graphic Adapter Adapter... Yeah, the poorly written BIOS/UEFI is quite telling of the low quality of the Biostar brand.

Comment: I'll take a look on that

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Not a single of those options works for me?

Comment: What doesn't work? The discrete card?

Comment: Yes, it is not being recognize

Comment: I'm not sure that board support multi-monitor, the feature that would allow for both cards to be used simultaneously so, if you have the default setting - let's call it "auto" - and you have a cable connected to the onboard port then it's likely the onboard only is being given to the OS. You need to either select PCI-e only and/or *not* connect anything to the motherbord's video port, only to the Nvidia card.

Comment: Well, i have a monitor connected to the onboard graphics and the other one to the geforce graphic. I'll do as you say and plug in the monitor to the geforce and leave the motherboard alone.

Comment: Also, I'm not used to manipulate my computer this much so i would like to know. This geforce graphic has three different port to plug in my monitor. can I have multi-monitor functionallity if I plug in two monitors there?

Comment: Nothing yet, it is now working